# Get value in xml from c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This question must be easy, but I faced a problem, 
which I can't deal with. 
No matter what I try I am unable to parse this xml with linq and get the xml value.

The error is "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I want to find the Xelement attribute.value which children have a concrete attribute.value.
How can I get the attribute.value?

thanks

xml

```
 <submitInfo>
    <setting name="file1" file ="example3.c" info ="open it!" serializeAs="String">
      <add name="file11" program="example2.c" />
      <add name="file12" value="example1.c" />
      <value />
<setting name="file2" file ="example23.c" info ="open it!" serializeAs="String">
      <add name="file21" program="example22.c" />
      <add name="file22" value="example21.c" />
      <value />

    </setting>
  </submitInfo>
```

code:

```
    var title1 = from q in doc.Element("content").Element("submitInfo").Elements("setting")
                 select q;

    foreach (var t1 in title1)
    {
          Console.WriteLine(
              String.Format( 
                 name = title1.Element("name").Value,
                 file= title1.Element("file").Value,
                 info= title1.Attribute("info").Value));
    }

    //get setting info
    var title = from p in doc.Element("content").Element("submitInfo").Element("setting").Elements("add")
                select p;
    foreach (var t1 in title)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
              String.Format(                      
                name =  title1.Element("name").Value,
                value = title1.Element("program").Value));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one problem:

```
 name = title1.Element("name").Value,
 file= title1.Element("file").Value,
 info= title1.Attribute("info").Value));
```

Look at your XML:

```
<setting name="file1" file ="example3.c" info ="open it!" serializeAs="String">
  <add name="file11" program="example2.c" />
  <add name="file12" value="example1.c" />
  <value />
</setting>
```

It doesn't have a `name` or `file` element - those are attributes. So you want something like:

```
string name = t1.Attribute("name");
string file = t1.Attribute("file");
string info = t1.Attribute("info");
```

Note that this is using `t1`, not `title1` - otherwise you're asking for the data from the query, rather than for the specific element of the query.

Additionally, you really don't need a query expression here. Just use:

```
var title1 = doc.Element("content").Element("submitInfo").Elements("setting");
```

Another problem is that you're currently calling `string.Format` with three assignments inside. I suspect you actually wanted:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", t1.Attribute("name"),
                  t1.Attribute("file"), t1.Attribute("info"));
```

Comment: I must use ""attributes"?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element'

Comment: Well just saying "always show error" doesn't give us any information. What error? Have you tried the code in the bottom of the answer? That should replace the code in your first `foreach` loop.

Comment: @mayumiTai: I suspect that problem is due to you using `title1` instead of `t1`.

Comment: The error is "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @mayumiTai: Yes, again, because you're trying to call it on `title1`. You've got the same sort of problem in the second part of your code too - I would get rid of that to start with, and just use the first part.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to ask when I chang xml(have file2)
But I can't get file2 info 
How can I solve it thanks

Change the title displayed at the top there is the problem

Comment: @mayumi: It's not clear what you mean. I suggest you ask a new question with your new code and a full description of the problem.